# Facebook isn't generating previews when I link to images

Tags: facebook

If I drop a link to an image, the link will often remain as just a link, rather than generating the preview of the image alongside my comment and link to the URL.

Sometimes it works, but more recently it doesn't generate previews most of the time. Sometimes it's taken a few edits to get it to generate the preview. Other times I've found that dropping the link in first and then adding a comment generates the preview. Neither of these are consistent, however.

Any ideas what's going wrong and how it can be fixed?

Comment: upgrade internet connection .Get a fast broadband connection.I guess its getting timed out.

Comment: Shouldn't 20mbps be fast enough already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the only way to fix image previews is to submit them to Facebook's debugging tool before posting them.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

After submitting, a preview should be generated for the URL.